# Does a compression valve come with the tub insert and compression sleeve or they have to be acquired separately?

Tags: plumbing

I would like to buy this (or any other 3/8 compression valve, not to make this specific for this product)
https://www.lowes.ca/product/38-in-dia-chrome-compression-quarter-turn-straight-valve-586694
Does it come with a compression sleeve and with the tube insert shown in the images below. Also does it work with both copper and the below 3/8" pressure rated tube?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A worker at the tool store can tell you for sure, but generally compression fittings include everything you need to complete the connection, assuming you choose the correct fitting.  The tube insert appears to be a brass tube sticking out of the compression nut in the picture.  Your diagram shows the parts separately because it is a guide designed to aid in a minimal repair.

Comment: yeah that is my problem the stores are closed for in store shopping due to pandemic so I have to order online :-(

Comment: the valve in the link is not designed to attach to 1/2" pipe, it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about using this valve for the application in your picture where it shows a valve, **it will not work**.

It is the wrong valve for your application. It is 3/8" compression *on both sides*.

The valve you are looking for is much more common than the valve in your link. You need a 1/2" nominal comp. inlet (5/8" o.d.) x 3/8" comp. outlet, 1/4 turn, straight configuration. **Any** decent plumbing shop will have what you need, although I can't speak for low-skill/high-volume "bix box" hardware stores...

Comment: the plan is to insert it in line on the 3/8 line that goes to the water purifier. WHat I have in place is a 1/2x3/8x3/8 tee (faucet and water purifier fed by a 1/2" copper, with a 3/8 copression hose attached to the tee toward the faucet and 3/8 pvc piper toward the purifier)

Comment: Yes then the valve could thread to the tee and your 3/8" PVC tube can thread to the valve. You should edit the fact that you are using it that way into your question.